# autocomplete value in textbox codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have done to make control autocomplete, but I have a problem to post data with jquery.

```
<input type="text" id="matakuliah" class="med" name="matakuliah">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(this).ready( function() {
            $("#matakuliah").autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,

                source:
                function(req, add){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('bahanAjar/lookup'); ?>",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:req,
                        success:   
                        function(data){
                            if(data.response =="true"){
                                add(data.message);
                            }
                        },
                    });
                },


            });
        });
</script>
```

on my controller

```
function lookup(){
        // process posted form data (the requested items like province)
        $keyword = $this->input->post('term');

        $data['response'] = 'false'; //Set default response
        $query = $this->matakuliah_model->lookup($keyword); //Search DB
        if( ! empty($query) )
        {
            $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response
            $data['message'] = array(); //Create array
            foreach( $query as $row )
            {
                $data['message'][] = array(
                                        'id_matakuliah'=>$row->id,
                                        'value' => $row->matakuliah,
                                        ''
                                     );  //Add a row to array
            }
        }
        if('IS_AJAX')
        {
            echo json_encode($data); //echo json string if ajax request

        }
        else
        {
           $this->load->view('admin/bahan_ajar/form_manage_file_view', $data); //Load html view of search results
        }
    }
```

The code work it well, but I want to add parameter to call database.

```
 $query = $this->matakuliah_model->lookup($keyword, $id_matakuliah);
```

like this. how I can get

```
$this->input-<post('id_matakuliah')
```

from jquery before.;

and I have another textbox for fill value of autocomplete from textbox matakuliah.

```
`<input type="hidden" id="matakuliah_post" class="med" name="matakuliah_post">`
```

When I'm use autocomplete textbox automatic fill another textbox, please help me.

Comment: In your script `function(req, add)` what is the value of `req`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `req` will contain `{term:"your search term"}`. Your can extend this javascript object to pass extra data. If you want to post `id_matakuliah`, you can assign its value like following before `$.ajax` call:

```
req.id_matakuliah = "Whatever you want to send";
```